# Am I capturing this JSON value correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How would I parse this JSON string?

```
{"nodes":["content"],"pager":"content"}
```

This is the function I'm using to grah the json.

```
 $.getJSON(dataNodes, {

 }, function (data) {

      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           $('#content').append(?????data.nodes?????);
      }

 });
```

I'm using data.nodes to try to capture that nodes value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.nodes` is an array with one value ("content"), so if you are trying to append that string then you should use:

```
data.nodes[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, been a slow day at work, and my developer changes the way my json string was structured :)

Comment: @inertialmedia No probelmo :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "parse" it, since jQuery will take care of it for you.

To do the append, you need to take the string out of the Array.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       $('#content').append(data[i].nodes[0]);
  }
```

But I prefer to do it like this.

```
var $content = $('#content');
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
    content.append(value.nodes[0]);
});
```

Comment: Although I wonder if it is an array of objects and the question only shows one object, since the question refers to "that nodes value". Makes it seems like there are several nodes.

Comment: I can't add comments anywhere but here, so I can't ask the questioner about it.

Comment: Considering he was looping over data and that an array can be JSON it is a valid argument and we might be wrong to assume he his getting an object.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the wrong thing, you need to iterate over data.nodes your content array and for loop remember to use $.each() it's cleaner :)

http://jsfiddle.net/n65D4/

```
$(function() {
    var data = {
        "nodes": ["content"],
        "pager": "content"
    };
    $.each(data.nodes, function(i, val) {
        $('#foo').append(val);
    });
});​
```